# Loop em autocomplete JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando este plugin - [jquery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Eu tenho um `select option` e o plugin cria dinamicamente um `input type="text"` e esconde o `select`. Tudo funciona!

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que, a cada letra que eu digitar, fazer uma busca no banco de dados para saber se existe uma palavra igual.

Na verdade, eu apenas preciso descobrir como percorrer o `input text` criado a cada letra digitada.
Alguma orientação?

Aqui está o projeto que peguei para usar: http://jsfiddle.net/emirdeliz/swqwLfxu/

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação você usa? Php, Java, C#, Pyton?

Comment: Php e JQuery. Só que nesse caso só tem o JQuery envolvido!

Comment: @CarlosRocha, você quer que o DataSource do Autocomplete seja Remoto? tipo, o autocomplete mostrar os 10 primeiros resultados vindos do banco que contenham o texto informado.

Comment: Não. Seguinte. O meu Select já foi populado pelo banco. Normal. Agora, o JQuery criou uma caixa de texto pois um select não aceita digitação. A cada letra que digito na caixa de text criada pelo plugin, ele vai autocompletando com as ocorrências que existem no select, correto? O que eu queria é que à medida que o autocomplete encontre correspondências enquanto esta autocompletando, seja feita uma busca no banco. Essa busca eu sei fazer, mas esse loop letra por letra não sei!

Comment: Puxa, ninguém sabe essa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionei a linha 17 e as linhas 32 a 45.

http://jsfiddle.net/swqwLfxu/42/

Comment: Rapaz, era isso mesmo que eu queria! Acho que eu preciso estudar um pouco de definições de JQuery. Cheguei a disparar um alert nessa mesma posição como ***$(" <input> ").on("keydown", function() {alert($(" <input> ").val());})***. O ***keydown*** disparava, mas o ***alert()*** só dava que o campo é ***indefinido***! Acho que vou ter que fazer isso também para ***onkeyup***.*** Agora só mais uma coisa: Como faço para saber se o que já foi digitado no campo texto existe, ou na li ou no campo texto, existe uma  combinação com alguma opção do select (ou text() de alguma li?***

Comment: O keydown executa uma função quando uma tecla é precionada, ou seja, antes mesmo da letra ser inserida no campo. O keyup já é chamado quando soltamos a tecla.

Comment: Verdade, falta de atenção da minha parte. ***Agora só mais uma coisa: Como faço para saber se o que já foi digitado no campo texto existe, ou na li ou no campo texto, existe uma combinação com alguma opção do select (ou text() de alguma li?***

Comment: To meio enrolado aqui, se não conseguir mais tarde faço mais um código, mas a idéia é dentro do keyup, fazer um loop nos campos comparando os valore. Pra facilitar, você pode criar um array na raiz do plugin, e guardar o valor de todos os campos, assim é só você fazer um loop nesse array

Comment: Tudo bem, vou tentando aqui também. Mas de antemão, muito obrigado pelo apoio!

Comment: Acho que cinsegui, porem, se o nome do plano é ***1 MB FULL*** e eu digitar ***1 mb full***. Isto é, minúsculo, a busca no array não encontra! Como se resolve esse problema de case insensitive?

Comment: na comparação, dentro do loop, a idéia é fazer assim: `if ( valordigitado.toLowerCase() == itemdoarray[ i ].toLowerCase() )`, assim vai tranformar todo o valor digitado em minusculo, e também vai transformar o valor a ser verificado em minusculo. Dessa forma, independente de como você digitar e como o item está no array, ele serão vamos dizer 'compatíveis'

Comment: É, eu fiz assim mesmo. E passei o valor normal para o php fazer a busca. do preço do plano. Deu certinho! novamente, eu muito obrigado.

Comment: Só mais 1 coisa. Eu tenho 2 selects na página que eu uso o plugin. então, quando os eventos ocorrem ocorrem para ambos selects. eu fiz       ***$(document).on("click", "li", function() {*** que$ são as li's geradas Se eu cliko nas li's do select planos, dispara o evento. Se eu cliko no select dos clientes, também dispara. Algum recurso?